# Restrict Rewrite Rule to One Domain

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache-2.2

I have hosting with GoDaddy, and my account supports multiple domains. My directory structure looks like ~/html, and then ~/html/site1, ~/html/site2, etc. In ~/html I have files for my "main" website, then in ~/html/site1 etc, I have files for my other domains.

The root site is a CakePHP site using mod_rewrite for pretty URLs. When I have the rewrite rules in place it breaks site1, site2, and so on. So I need to tweak my .htaccess to ignore those other sites.

Is there a rule I can add which will not apply mod_rewrite and .htaccess to the subfolders containing my other sites?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a RewriteCond using the %{HTTP_HOST} parameter so that the rules will only be used if the host matches the right domain.

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.tld$

Comment: Thanks! It took me a while to figure out this RewriteCond condition must precede every rule in my .htaccess file, but I got it working.